# What is the difference between the waswas (whispering) of the nafs (soul) and Satan

Tags: shaitan, definitions

To simplify my question: What is the difference between the waswas (whispering) of the nafs (soul) and Satan? And how can we know when a thought is bad and from Satan and not just critical thinking that could be good?

For my deeper analyse and questions read through this:

---

### Satan

As the most believe, Satan whispers into mans heart:

> 114:4-5
>    مِن شَرِّ الْوَسْوَاسِ الْخَنَّاسِ
>    الَّذِي يُوَسْوِسُ فِي صُدُورِ النَّاسِ
>   From the evil of the retreating whisperer -
>   Who whispers [evil] into the breasts of mankind

And:

> 20:120
>    **فَوَسْوَسَ** إِلَيْهِ الشَّيْطَانُ قَالَ يَا آدَمُ هَلْ أَدُلُّكَ عَلَىٰ شَجَرَةِ الْخُلْدِ وَمُلْكٍ لَّا يَبْلَىٰ
>   Then **Satan whispered** to him; he said, "O Adam, shall I direct you to the tree of eternity and possession that will not deteriorate?"

I know there are more verses and hadiths about this. Those are so popular so I guess I don't need to go in detail about them.

### The soul

It also seem to me that the humans nafs (soul, mind, subconscious...) itself is, i.e the human itself is blamed for actions or impulses. For instance, regarding Yusuf when the woman tried to seduce him, Yusuf himself is speaking about the nafs and not Satan: (surat Yusuf)

> And (with passion) did she desire him, and **he would have desired her**,
>   but that he saw the evidence of his Lord: thus (did We order) that We
>   might turn away from him (all) evil and shameful deeds: for he was one
>   of Our servants, sincere and purified.

Later on...

> He said: "O my Lord! the prison is more to my liking than that to which they invite me: Unless Thou turn away their snare from me, **I should (in my youthful folly) feel inclined towards them** and join the ranks of the ignorant."
>
> So his Lord answered his invocation and turned away from him their
>   plot. Verily, He is the All-Hearer, the All-Knower.

Now in the later verses when freed from prison and the woman admits her fault of trying to seduce him and the planing to put him in prison, Yusuf then says:

> "Nor do I absolve my own self (of blame): **the (human) soul is certainly prone to evil**, unless my Lord do bestow His Mercy: but surely my Lord is Oft-forgiving, Most Merciful."
>
> وَمَا أُبَرِّئُ نَفْسِي ۚ **إِنَّ النَّفْسَ لَأَمَّارَةٌ بِالسُّوءِ** إِلَّا مَا رَحِمَ رَبِّي ۚ إِنَّ رَبِّي غَفُورٌ رَّحِيمٌ

In these verses (I find it) clearly that **the soul itself has its own impulses or desires which the Satan is free of blame**. The only blame is on ourselves (our souls)

> 50:16
>   It was We Who created man, **and We know what dark suggestions his soul makes to him**: for We are nearer to him than (his) jugular vein.
>
> وَلَقَدْ خَلَقْنَا الْإِنسَانَ وَنَعْلَمُ مَا **تُوَسْوِسُ بِهِ نَفْسُهُ**
>   ۖ وَنَحْنُ أَقْرَبُ إِلَيْهِ مِنْ حَبْلِ الْوَرِيدِ

Continuing...

> 4:79
>   What comes to you of good is from Allah , but what c**omes to you
>   of evil, [O man], is from yourself**.
>
> مَّا أَصَابَكَ مِنْ حَسَنَةٍ
>   فَمِنَ اللَّهِ ۖ وَمَا أَصَابَكَ مِن سَيِّئَةٍ **فَمِن نَّفْسِكَ**

It seems we shouldn't put the blame on someone else as humans, even blaming satan (or other people) for our failure, seems to be the wrong idea:

> 3:165
>   What! When a single disaster smites you, although ye smote
>   (your enemies) with one twice as great, do ye say?- "Whence is this?"
>   Say (to them): "**It is from yourselves:** For Allah hath power over all
>   things."
>
> أَوَلَمَّا أَصَابَتْكُم مُّصِيبَةٌ قَدْ أَصَبْتُم
>    مِّثْلَيْهَا قُلْتُمْ أَنَّىٰ هَٰذَا ۖ **قُلْ هُوَ مِنْ عِندِ
>   أَنفُسِكُمْ ۗ** إِنَّ اللَّهَ عَلَىٰ كُلِّ شَيْءٍ قَدِيرٌ

### Some thoughts and questions

There are plenty more verses and hadiths that are talking about the nafs (soul, self, ego?). These are just some references to make you able to answer in a better way.

Now, it seems to me that the nafs is responsible and also can be blamed (i.e not only the waswas of Satan).

1. **What is the difference between the whispering (waswas) of Satan and the "whispering" *(or inclinations, impulses?)* of the nafs
   (human soul, ego, mind..)?**
2. **How do we determine whether a thought is from Satan or just from ourselves?**
3. **Can we have bad thoughts that just are from ourselves?** Or are **ALL** bad thoughts from Satan? *What is the proof of that? (doesn't "inna nafsa la'ammaraton bi so'i" contradict this?)*
4. **How do we know that a thought is bad (from the nafs or shaytan) and not good?** *In some cases for instance, if you really have
       doubts about a matter which the vast majority follows, the vast
       majority would say that those thoughts or doubts are from Satan.
       What if those thoughts are right and in this scenario, the majority
       is wrong. Then this wouldn't really be a bad thought from the Satan.
       How can we know which of these thoughts are from Satan and which are
       not? (this is just an example)*

   Here comes a real example: *Let us assume if I think "I don't believe a jinn can take over the human or listen to our thoughts"... Would this be waswas from shaytan? I guess, if it's wrong, yes then it might be... But if it isn't wrong, it shouldn't be from shaytan. How do we know a thought like this (or similar) is just from my own mind and not from Satan?*

   These thoughts can be TRUE. How would I know they are true but not Satan messing with my head to make me understand the religion in a wrong way? You see, **if I am right, Satan says you are wrong! Stay away! You are on deep water now! You will become a disbeliever if you think like this! If I am wrong he might say "You are right!"** Sometimes maybe he isn't saying a word. How do you determine something important like that?

Comment: My understanding is that there is always a shaitaan in our body, which whispers evil thoughts in our ears...
Now, once he has whispered something our mind will automatically reason for it, and in result there will be more wasawas, or some clarity, wither of this will happen. Like it says in a hadees shaitaan says to man, who made that thing, man thinks Allah, that it whispers who made you he says Allah, and so on.. in the end he says, who made Allah... now on this point our mind is reasoning that if there is always a creator, what about Allah, answer to this is separate thing.

Comment: But what i am trying to say is clear form this, that he whispered one thing, and then another and then another, and let the mind reason based on those whispers, so our mind is saying this is not possible for god to exist without cretor, shaitaan didn't directly said that how a god can exist without creation by someone... i think i made the point

Comment: Thanks for commenting! Even though there always is a Satan in our body or not my other questions are still unanswered. Cuz that wasn't the question.

Comment: Firstly, there is no reason to know a thought is from shaitan or yourself, a bad thought, a bad reasoning is just bad, wheather it appeared from within you or shaitan whispered it, secondly, a thought is bad when it is suggesting something against islam's principles, and its teachings, or is denying something like mairaaj... Muslim is a person who BELIEVES... Iman is believing so, any thought which is leading to disbelief or any confusion in belief, or anything against sunnah, it is bad. There is no rocket science i think..

Comment: I understand what you are trying to say. But I do disagree with some of your points. But the problem here is if we cannot know if a thought is from Satan or just from the soul, why do we keep blaming Satan every single time (when we don't know for sure)?, we shouldn't speak about what we don't know. That would be ghayb (unknown), and no human has the right to speak about the ghayb. So if I cannot differ between whispering from Satan and a thought from the soul i think we should stop saying it's from satan first of all!

Comment: There are things people believe is from Islam, but isn't. Their scholars keep telling them it's satan that is giving them doubt about these matters. Their doubts are critical thinking and right! (this is an example) But because they are so afraid of Satans whispering, they get trapped. So I believe it isn't that clear like you try to describe it. This might be why it's important to know if a thought is from satan or not...

Comment: Maybe soul is the medium used by Satan to whisper us?

Comment: So, as i said earlier, that if any thought is bad in your mind, it is directly or indirectly by result of shaitaan whispering, in your ear, in ear of a person you heard or read, or anything like that. Like when Adam ate the forbidden fruit, he didn't do it because of his own critical thinking, shaitaan whispered in his ear and made him do the wrong thing. So, all bad thoughts are directly or indirectly because of shaitaan... Even if we disagre with this, shaitaan is responsible for pushing us out of the heaven, and that lead to all the bad things, even bad thoughts in this world..

Comment: @ZiaUlRehmanMughal Let us assume if I think "I don't believe a jinn can take over the human or listen to our thoughts"... Would this be waswas from shaytan? I guess, if it's wrong, yes then it might be... But if it isn't wrong, it shouldn't be from shaytan. Right? You see my point? How do we know a thought like this (or similar) is just from my own mind and not from Satan?

Comment: And my point here is, that we don't HAVE to classify our thoughts as waswasa form shaitan or anything else or even yourself, whatever is against islam, quran and hadees and is trying to make reasoning is a waswa, its that simple.

Comment: @ZiaUlRehmanMughal I respect your view but I don't agree fully on this because this really reminds me about some circular reasoning that takes you nowhere. I am afraid no one really knows the true answer on this question.  I'll wait and see if we get more answers.

Comment: That's because, what i think, this is a really deep answer, and after getting answer to this question, i don't know if you will gain a few more deeds, or will avoid some of your sins in any way. But, anyway, good luck with it.

Answer (score 2):

Terminology: **`نفس = self`** & **`شیطان = satan`**

I think the knowledge on Satan is very obvious, but the knowledge on *self* isn't. I would refer from [Munajaat of Imam Ali](http://www.duas.org/ramazan/munajaat_e_amir.htm). ( I have cut out some of its parts, you can see its complete version in the link)

In this Munajaat, Imam Ali shows us who we are before Allah.

- My Lord, O my Lord, You are the Master and I am the **Slave**, and who else can be merciful to the slave except the Master?
- My Lord, O my Lord, You are the Mighty and I am the **low**, and who else can be merciful to the low except the Mighty?
- My Lord, O my Lord, You are the Glorious and I am the **miserable**, and who else can be merciful to the miserable except the Glorious?
- My Lord, O my Lord, You are the Powerful and I am the **weak**, and who else can be merciful to the weak except the Powerful?
- My Lord, O my Lord, You are the Wealthy and I am the **Poor**, and who else can be merciful to the poor except the Wealthy?
- My Lord, O my Lord, You are the Provider and I am the **blessed**, and who else can be merciful to the blessed except the Provider?
- My Lord, O my Lord, You are the Generous and I am the **MISER**, and who else can be merciful to the miser except the Generous?
- My Lord, O my Lord, You are the Forgiver and I am the **sinner**, and who else can be merciful to the sinner except the Forgiver?
- My Lord, O my Lord, You are the High-handed and I am the **humble**, and who else can be merciful to humble the except the High-handed?

That's who we are.
But there's more to it. Are we as ourselves powerful? or is it Allah who gives us power? Are we as ourselves intelligent? or is Allah that has given us intelligence? Are we as ourselves with body (that can walk, speak, move objects? or is it Allah that has given us our body? Can we age on our own? Or is it Allah that ages us through? Can we provide nourishment on our own? Or is it Allah that is providing sustenance to us?

We have nothing by ourselves. NOTHING. Repeat that 5 times. :)
The only ability that we have is: We accept whatever that Allah gives us.

For such a weak being that is *poor, miser, low, slave, sinner, humble* , there will be struggle. It will want more. It will do things that it shouldn't do. That why we say *و ما توفیقی الا بالله* ( And my success is not but through Allah) <sup>[2](https://quran.com/11/88)</sup> so that Allah will help to protect us. [Or in the story of Prophet Yusuf (who is a human that is also created weak, poor,etc.), what did Yusuf say? How did he get out of the situation? He got out by Allah showing him the path. I repeat 'showing the path'. Allah didn't enforce Prophet Yusuf hands/body/will from not doing it. God enlightened his wisdom: *had he not seen the **proof of his Lord*** <sup>[3](https://quran.com/)</sup>. Yusuf was still able to choose sin. <— This is why a prophet's infallible-ness is attributed to himself and to God (some people wrongly think God makes prophets infallible and the prophets themselves are doing nothing, some others think the opposite. But its both. **God enlightens** the heart/wisdom and the **prophet chooses** the right path even though they can choose to sin.)]. Had Prophet Yusuf been a 'great' sinner then, ختم الله قلوبهم **could** have effected on him to the extent that he would have not seen the 'proof of his Lord' ie the light of wisdom, the gift of Allah that helps us be guided.

To answer your questions:

> What is the difference between the whispering (waswas) of Satan and
>   the "whispering" (or inclinations, impulses?) of the nafs (human soul,
>   ego, mind..)?

Nafs whispering comes from our weakness. Satan's whispering comes because he wants to send us all to hell.

> How do we determine whether a thought is from Satan or just from ourselves?

It's usually a bit of both. Hard to dissect. Yet Satan could *invite* (not force) your friend to call you to an evil activity. Nafs can't do such, it's limited to yourself. Nafs usually goes for personal gain, Satan may have broader purposes, like destroying an entire nation or a group of people.

> Can we have bad thoughts that just are from ourselves?

Yes. The poorness in us is what makes us steal, or be jealous of one who has more money. The misery in us makes us selfish. I don't mean that we are created by an evil clay, no never. I mean our *self* has nothing, by having nothing it will have a *tendency* to do more evil than it does to do good. Though Allah doesn't leave us there. He gives us wisdom. See below.

> How do we know that a thought is bad (from the nafs or shaytan) and not good?

By using your wisdom *عقل* (of Allah's greatest gifts) which is given to you by Allah. But that's very tricky. We all do have wisdom right? So how do some people decide to kill others and some decide to protect? 
We to ourselves had nothing, then Allah gave us wisdom, then some of us sinned and didn't repent and sinned again and didn't repent and sinned again and didn't repent and then Allah decided to *"Allah has set a seal upon their hearts and upon their hearing, and over their vision is a veil. And for them is a great punishment."<sup>[4](https://quran.com/2/7)</sup>*

At the same time others sin, but then repent it, they basically keep their gift less effected. The prophets of God, were the most right doing, because they had minimum sin ie no effect/veil on their heart/wisdom.

Aside from not sinning as general advice : *So when you recite the Qur'an, [first] seek refuge in Allah from Satan, the expelled [from His mercy].<sup>[5](https://quran.com/16/98)</sup>* so for your question that would be seek Allah's help at all moments.

Comment: Thanks, this is looking much better now.  +1 ..
About the last question,  I am not refering to bad thoughts as in "kill people and sin". I am more talking about thoughts that make you doubt some special questions about your religion. These thoughts can be TRUE. How would I know they are true but not Satan messing with my head to make me understand the religion in a wrong way? You see, if I am right, satan says you are wrong! Stay away! If I am wrong he might say "You are right!" Sometimes maybe he isn't saying a word, you are right or wrong. How do you determine something important like that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44697/discussion-between-honey-and-kilise).

Comment: If you could add it in the answer that would be a perfect answer. Also I forgot to ask, could you add some references to your answers (if possible and if available)

Comment: @ZiaUlRehmanMughal I will gradually add references to my answer. I don't have references off the top of my head. Though just added details to Prophet's Yusuf's story and have already included 5 references/links

Comment: I appreciate your efforts, but many of your answers just seem like your own thoughts without references.

Comment: @ZiaUlRehmanMughal reference? Read that dua and then look into yourself. Do you truly believe your clay was made powerful or weak? When you look into yourself do you sense that you are dependent on a higher person—every second? **The reference is yourself** Do you really need a reference to know there is a God, that he is just? or upon admonition and reflection by your wisdom you understand it? I think understanding 2 points are key: 1) where do we stand before Allah 2) What gift is wisdom. ( I previously saw an answer on SE, I'll search, but again mostly this is a matter of self-reflect.

Comment: @ZiaUlRehmanMughal If every living person today came to you and told you are God, would you believe? No, because of that  self-reflect and wisdom. If every being came and told you there is no God, again because of the gift of wisdom which makes us humans stand above a wall, rock or animals we know better. We are recommended to use our wisdom and not just always look for references. *افلا تدبرون؟ افلا تعقلون؟ بل اکثرهم لا یعقلون/ فاتبرو یا اولی الابصار* . Yet what I said isn't contradicting Quran, and it's extracted from it.

Comment: I really appreciate all your hard work in this answer, but still, this answer lacks juice. Only logical reasoning is not enough to understand shariah... And yes, there are a few points in your answer, i think, are not right. But i don't want to have a debate here, so i am just asking to add a few references, specially to the answers to sub questions. Jazakallah

Comment: @ZiaUlRehmanMughal so far you have only asked for references. If you have a few questions, it won't be a debate. Perhaps there is something wrong or something that could be edit. Comments are used for that exactly and so far I have made multiple edits. So tell me what you think isn't right, I would either change or not. But not saying them isn't the correct approach on SE.

Comment: @Honey I updated my notes on my question 4 yesterday if you wish you could edit your answer accordingly.  Also I don't care about the references but I know others who read this would like some, that is why I am asking you to add some If you do got some.

Comment: @Kilise I don't see much of a change in your question. As a rule of thumb. We have 2 major proofs. Quran (+ majority of narrations) + Aql. You have to holdfast to these and reflect for whatever that comes your way. Try it with Quran and with a pure heart. Give sadaqa, do istiqfar and have 100% faith in Allah at ALL moments. Don't try to rely on yourself, you would fail! I don't think you can kill Satan but when you say بسم الله الرحمن الرحیم when you made wudu before reading Quran, when you do it at the best times and have kept your heart from sinning, then chances of Satan's harm is reduced.

Comment: You find the changes in my two last paragraphs.

Comment: @Kilise I did read it. But I don't how to answer it better. Perhaps in a few days I could come with something better or you may have a different understanding of it. Read quran and try to reflect and read surah falaq. *الا بذكر الله تطمئن القلوب*. Inshallah the waswas would go away.

Comment: @Honey All right. I am looking forward to reading it if you do try later. Thank you may Allah increase our belief and increase our understanding of how He want us to follow the religion.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you came across [this fatwa](http://fatwa.islamweb.net/fatwa/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=114571) (in Arabic).

The waswasa or whispering of the nafs is all (bad things, acts) you may think about or have in mind ...

> قال السمعاني: الوسوسة حديث النفس.
>  وقال البيضاوي: ما تحدثه به نفسه وهو ما يخطر بالبال، والوسوسة الصوت الخفي.

Also you can read [this hadith](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/83/42) which was narrated on the authority of abu Hurairah in several hadith collections (in more or less the same wording).

> The Prophet (ﷺ) said, "Allah forgives my followers those (evil deeds) their souls may whisper or suggest to them as long as they do not act (on it) or speak."

Allah says about this:

> ... Whether you show what is within yourselves or conceal it, Allah will bring you to account for it. ... [2:284](http://legacy.quran.com/2/284)

This means Allah know what is inside our souls and minds (or nafs) as 
 said in tafsir [ibn kathir](http://www.qtafsir.com/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=111):

> There are many other Ayat on this subject. In this Ayah (2:284), Allah states that He has knowledge of what the hearts conceal, and consequently, He will hold the creation accountable for whatever is in their hearts. This is why when this Ayah was revealed, it was hard on the Companions, since out of their strong faith and conviction, they were afraid that such reckoning would diminish their good deeds. ...

Note that *bringing to account* does not necessary need to mean that one would be punished based on this account as you may read in the following verses especially [2:286](http://legacy.quran.com/2/286), which clearly eases the meaning one could conclude from 2:284.

The above fatwa also quotes from majmo' al-fatwa of ibn Tyamiyyah a quote of abu Hazem explaining the difference of both kind of whispering:

> وقد ذكر أبو حازم في الفرق بين وسوسة النفس والشيطان فقال: ما كَرِهَتْه نفسُك لنفسك فهو من الشيطان فاستعذ بالله منه، وما أحبته نفسك لنفسك فهو من نفسك فانهها عنه
>   
>   Abu Hazem said comparing between the whispering caused by the nafs and that caused by the Satan, and said: Whatever your nafs hates for your nafs is from Satan, so seek refuge with Allah from it. And whatever your nafs likes for your nafs is from your nafs so forbid it to it.

So what you would hate for yourself (but not for others) is whispering from satan. And what you'd like for yourself (not for others) is whispering from your nafs.

In [this fatwa](https://islamqa.info/en/39684) the whispering of human "Satan's" is also quoted beside the above two kinds of whispering. In [this thread](http://www.ahlalhdeeth.com/vb/showthread.php?t=329446) the author pretends that the nafs is just following the whispering of his jinn attache (based on [this hadith](http://sunnah.com/muslim/52/62)).

Comment: +1 Thanks, I'll go through your answer in more details soon when I got more time in sha Allah. I have done a bit more research since I asked this question. Defined terms more deeper; waswas ,shaytan, the different states of a nafs (nafs ammaraa bi so2, lawwama, motmain and so on) ... spoke to a deaf about my question how stan whispers to a deaf and so on

Answer (score 0):

Read it from start to end
First off all keep in mind that Waswasa of shaitan is just relating to confusing thoughts.                       The thoughts of waswasa can be obsession, doubts, negative/intrusive thoughts,bad thoughts (badgumani) and others etc.
But not all bad thoughts are waswasa for example if anybody feels jealous from any other person, then it is not waswasa of shaitan, because you don't confuse of being jealous.
Similarly not all thoughts in which you confuse are waswasa.    For example if you think, Should I choose this cloth to wear or that, then it is also not waswasa of shaitan, because it is not a bad thought.
What I am going to brief is that you can easily understand that which thought is waswasa or something else.
Try this formula, you can definitely assess that whether it is waswasa or not.
The formula is NCTFRPM
Where
N= Nature of thought i.e Good, Bad or Any other
C= Confusion i.e Yes or No
T= Type of thought i.e Obsession, Doubts, Negative thoughts and Bad thoughts (Bad gumani) etc
F= Feelings i.e Fear, anger, hate, worry and sad
R= Repetitive again and again i.e Yes or No
P= Psychotic Check i.e does all other think like me or not
M= Mental illness i.e Anxiety (for long term), Depression, Schizophrenia, Bipolar disorder, Hallucinations etc
Let me clear you with 2 examples

1. Suppose a person thinks that he might have divorced his wife. He can check easily that Is it shaitan waswasa or not.
   Apply the formula
   N= Nature of thought= Bad
   C= Confusion= Yes
   T= Type of thought= Doubt
   F= Felling= Sad
   R= Repetitive again and again = Yes
   P= Psychosis check= No all other people don't think like this
   M= Mental illness= Depression
   It shows that is waswasa of shaitan
2. Suppose a women is raped and she think to suicide.
   Apply the formula
   N= Nature of thought= Bad
   C= Confusion= Yes
   T= Type of thought= Nothing else
   F= Feeling= Sad
   R= Repetitive again and again= Yes
   P= Psychosis check= Yes others will also think like that
   M= Mental illness= Depression
   But it is not waswasa, because if we see T (Type of thought),then woman is not in doubt that she was raped. Although it is a bad thought to get suicide but it is not waswasa. The shaitan had trapped him through other way.

So, if all the formula applies completely to a thought then this is waswasa any if anyone thing is missed then it is not waswasa

Inshallah this will helpful for you
If still feel any problem you ca  ask
Jazak Allah